# Web API not reading connection string in production release

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, ado

I'm stymied by a problem I'm having reading a connection string for a Web API app.

I have a connection string set up in app.config as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Server=[server];Database=[db];User Id=user;Password=password;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

This is read from code as:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

All works fine in development (using the proper creds of course). However when I publish, the app.config is not copied over. I can manually recreate this file on the server, but even then I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user '[MACHINE NAME]'.
```

It appears that instead of grabbing the connection string from app.config the code is instead attempting to connection to SQL Server using a trusted connection.

Note that I'm using ADO and not EF.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't the connection string be inside `web.config`?

Comment: Good question! It didn't work in web.config but it did work in app.config. In development at least.

Comment: Could you show the web.config file?

Comment: Yes it should be in the `web.config`. What do you mean by 'it didn't work in web.config'?

Comment: Yeah a little vague, huh? I'm getting an object reference error using that same code and web.config only. Interestingly when I view the connection strings collection in debug I see one that's set up for SQL Express... but not sure where that's coming from because I don't see it in any config files.

Comment: It looks like your project isn't a full web application. Did you upgrade a class library to a web application? Anyways, I think your issue is solved if you create a new (empty) web application and move everything, except app.config, there. Web.config should be present now and should contain the connectionstring.